# How to get active connections count of a Kubernetes POD

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud

I am new to Kubernetes and for our application I need to find number of active connection of a pod. I analyzed a bit and got to know that we can get such data using Kubernetes addons like Istio. But I learnt that using such addons can lead to memory hit as the addon creates a kind of side car container for each pod to track such data.
Our application will be getting deployed finally in IBM cloud. I am not aware at the moment if there are any efficient addons which are specific to cloud service provider. I am still checking on it.

I could not get much from Kubernetes API. Would like to know if there is any other way to get active connection count of a Pod.

Comment: Have you considered to implement in your application a `HTTP` path like `/metrics` that would expose the `active-connection` metric and use [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) to scrape it?

Comment: I did some analysis and  learnt that HAproxy ingress stats has this count exposed. Still checking for further solutions.

Comment: Is there any way to get this info from API ?  i tried  readpodreadNamespacedPodStatusWithHttpInfo method, but it doesn't returns required info.

Comment: AFAIK you won't get the information about the number of active connections of a `Pod` from `kubeapi-server`. Have you managed to get this information from `Traefik`?